# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I have updated the Gradle plugin from 4.1 to 4.4 and also tried to upgrade the android plugin Gradle from 3.0.1 to 3.1.3. The problem is AS cannot update the android plugin and gives me this error.

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/F:/android studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom
file:/F:/android studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar
```

Based on the same questions I've added maven repo in Project level build.gradle in addition to google() used for AS 3.0 and higher but the problem hasn't been solved.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have "Enable embedded Maven repository" checked (in Prefrences / Settings menu)

Answer (score 1):

try alter and verify that in the "gradle-wrapper.properties"  file to amend the gradle dist  to a much later version for example

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

and also update the android support lib version to latest version as well for eg 27.1.1